# #1005 - Can't create table on ALTER TABLE when connecting table via FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am working on a homework assignment. I have to build a database for a video store. All of the following works:

```
CREATE TABLE Stock
(
PKStock_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKTitle VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
NoOfDVD INT(10) NOT NULL,
NoOfVHS INT(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PKStock_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
PKUnique_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
DistributorSerialNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Distributor_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKTitle_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
InStock CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
DateOut TIMESTAMP,
DateBack TIMESTAMP,
Customer_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Rental_Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PKUnique_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Movie
(
PKTitle_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKTitle_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(30),
Genre VARCHAR(8),
YearReleased INT,
Length INT,
PRIMARY KEY (PKTitle_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Actors
(
PKActor_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKActor_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
Actors VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (PKActor_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Awards
(
PKAward_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKAward_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Awards VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (PKAward_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Directors
(
PKDirector_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKDirector_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Directors VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (PKDirector_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ElectronicCatalogue
(
PKElectronicCatalogue VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKDistributor_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
DistributorSerialNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PKElectronicCatalogue)
);

CREATE TABLE Distributors
(
PKDistributor_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKDistributor_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
NameOfDistributer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Horror CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
Drama CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
Comedy CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
Action CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
Thrillers CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PKDistributor_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
PKCustomer_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FKUnique_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(30),
Address VARCHAR(100),
Phone INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PKCustomer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Fees
(
PKFee_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FK_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Damages DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
Late DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PKFee_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE Stock
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKTitle)
REFERENCES Inventory(PKUnique_ID);

ALTER TABLE Movie
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKTitle_ID)
REFERENCES Stock (PKStock_ID);

ALTER TABLE Actors
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKActor_ID)
REFERENCES Movie (PKTitle_ID);

ALTER TABLE Awards
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKAward_ID)
REFERENCES Movie (PKTitle_ID);

ALTER TABLE Directors
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKDirector_ID)
REFERENCES Movie (PKTitle_ID);

ALTER TABLE ElectronicCatalogue
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKDistributor_ID)
REFERENCES Inventory (PKUnique_ID);

ALTER TABLE Distributors
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKDistributor_ID)
REFERENCES ElectronicCatalogue (PKElectronicCatalogue);
```

I next want to connect the Inventory table to the customers table. When I do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKUnique_ID)
REFERENCES Inventory (Customer_ID);
```

I get this error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'mm.#sql-9f69_110' (errno: 150)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of the Customers table.

Comment: @DavidTunnell This is really Oracle? `INT(10)` isn't an Oracle type afaik.

Comment: I've retagged as MySQL. This question has nothing to do with Oracle.

Comment: I had to connect to my university's Nova oracle Unix server. Once I get the SQL prompt it says "Enter SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements."

Comment: @DavidTunnell - That error message is a MySQL message verbatim. Oracle errors always start with `ORA-`. If you are actually using Oracle, you are not connecting to the correct machine.

Comment: FKs should reference Unique or Primary Keys. I don't think that `Inventory (Customer_ID)` would (or should) be unique. In fact, most of your Foreign Key definitions seems awkward.

Comment: THis is a web interface for the server http://isqlplus.umuc.edu/isqlplus/ The above statements work for me when logged in.

Comment: @DavidTunnell If you run the above statements in Oracle you get `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` because `INT` is not a valid column type in Oracle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Foreign key should point to a unique column (primary key or unique). Your `Inventory (Customer_ID)` is not unique.

I think you are trying to :

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory
ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_Inv FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
REFERENCES Customers (PKCustomer_ID);
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why you didn't get the full message but there's a command line tool bundled with MySQL that provides further information about cryptic error messages like this (or you can just Google for the error code):

```
C:>perror 150
MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

If you have the `SUPER` privilege, you can get further details with this query:

```
show engine innodb status
```

And in this case you see this:

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130226 21:00:25 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/#sql-1d98_1:
FOREIGN KEY (FKUnique_ID)
REFERENCES Inventory (Customer_ID):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

So you are missing an index as explained.

**Edit:** As other answers point out, if there's no index it's because you're linking to the wrong column.

Answer (score 4):

As Álvaro G. Vicario says you are missing an index, this is because you are not correctly using foreign keys.

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKUnique_ID)
REFERENCES Inventory (Customer_ID);
```

This should be:

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
REFERENCES Customer(PKCustomer_ID);
```

The foreign key checks if the customer in the Inventory table actually exists in the Customers table. Thus Inventory here is the table you want to add the foreign key too and it references in primary key in the Customer table.

What you are trying to do is reference the Customer_ID in Inventory, which is just an VARCHAR(8)column and not an Primary Key (Index).

You should double check your other alter statements as well.

Comment: Very useful. In my answer, I didn't even pay attention to the tables themselves :)

Answer (score 0):

This turns out that you have different collation settings between these tables. In my case we had latin_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci